# Nginx Redirect depending on URL Param

Tags: url, redirect, nginx, param

I am new at nginx and need help with redirect (basically I am a Java Dev), so here is what I need suggestions for : I have a url https://www.mysite.com/abc?server=10.2.2.10

I want nginx to check if server param is set then it should rewrite url to

```
https://10.2.2.10/abc
```

here is what I have tried but it isn't working:

```
location /abc/{  # I have also tried with /abc
    if ($arg_server != ""){
        rewrite https://$arg_server/$1 permanent;
    }
}
```

any suggestions please? Thank you for any helps guys

best Regards
Sajid

Comment: by not working you mean doesn't do any thing or does it show an error ?

Comment: yes it does not do anything @MohammadAbuShady

Comment: It's really strange idea, to provide nginx a server name and have nginx redirect to that server. Why not just go to that server in first place?

Comment: actually first site is suppose to get data from 2nd one ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the rewrite seems wrong, try replacing the rewrite line with this

```
if ($arg_server != ""){
    return 301 https://$arg_server/$1;
}
```

Adding a `^` to your rewrite probably would have worked but it's better to use return instead of rewrite [here's why](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Taxing_Rewrites)

Also I believe running a simple `if($arg_server)` would work without the `!=` part, you can try it, Not sure though if it would work if it was empty string, like `example.com?server=`, if it does then  just ignore what i said

Comment: sure I am gonna give it a try right away Thank you :)

Comment: curl https://mysite.com/abc?server=someip -k
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>ngx_openresty/1.4.3.1</center>
</body>
</html>             I get above when I use  CURL but I do not get any request on the ip where nginx is suppose to redirect

Comment: probably because curl doesn't follow redirects, what does the browser do ? or try adding `-L` to curl

Comment: I guess it should be `https://$arg_server$uri`, because I don't see any regexp that fills `$1`.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady basically I am using AJAX call here is what I get: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://[new_ip_address]/abc. Origin https://mysite.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. I know It can be handled by CORs but I was wondering if there is any other way around?

Comment: just add the header to nginx, I think this is the best way to handle it, and I just noticed like @alexeyten said `$1` won't match any thing, funny I missed that, what do you actually want to be put at the `$1` position ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady actually I have already places $uri there... Thank you :)

Comment: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://[new_ip_address]/abc" means that redirect works. Now you have to handle with CORS, and that's completely different story. You could send header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` from your `[new_ip_address]` server. Or you could proxy request.